# Could registerForActivityResult be used in a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

The problem with this as I see it is that you have to guarantee that registerForActivityResult() is called before your own activity's OnCreate() completes. OnCreate() is obviously not a suspending function, so I can't wrap registerForActivityResult() and ActivityResultLauncher.launch() in a suspendCoroutine{} to wait for the callback, as I can't launch the suspendCoroutine from OnCreate and wait for it to finish before letting OnCreate complete...

...which I did think I might be able to do using runBlocking{}, but I have found that invoking runBlocking inside OnCreate causes the app to hang forever without ever running the code inside the runBlocking{} block.

So my question is whether runBlocking{} is the correct answer but I am using it wrong, or whether there is some other way to use registerForActivityResult() in a coroutine, or whether it is simply not possible at all.

Comment: have you tried using  `runBlocking(IO) {}` in onCreate so it would block the IO thread instead of the UI thread?

Comment: Don’t do that. Runblocking blocks the thread it was called from. Runblocking should never be used in an Android app, ever.

Comment: Whatever you’re trying to do is not possible. onCreate cannot wait for an Activity result because the next activity cannot be started until after this one is created.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this.
Please refer to the implementation below.

```kotlin
class RequestPermission(activity: ComponentActivity) {
    private var requestPermissionContinuation: CancellableContinuation<Boolean>? = null
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private val requestFineLocationPermissionLauncher =
        activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
            requestPermissionContinuation?.resumeWith(Result.success(isGranted))
        }

    suspend operator fun invoke(permission: String) = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
        requestPermissionContinuation = continuation
        requestFineLocationPermissionLauncher.launch(permission)
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            requestPermissionContinuation = null
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you initialize this class before onStart of the activity. `registerForActivityResult` API should be called before onStart of the activity. Refer to the sample below

```kotlin
class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    val requestPermission: RequestPermission = RequestPermission(this)

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val isGranted = requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            //Do your actions here
        }

    }
}
```